# Python 3 Reading File and counting the lines in the file

Tags: python-3.6

Write a function named "count_lines" that takes a string as a parameter representing the name of a file to read and returns the number of lines in the file.

I honestly don't fully understand what needs to be done to complete the task.
I know that I need the parameter to open the file name stored in the parameter, but not sure how to do it or the for loop to count the lines in the file itself.

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
def count_lines(filepath):
    with open(filepath, 'r+') as file:
        lines = file.readlines()
        return len(lines)
```

Comment: Thanks, I didn't even realize that I could return the length of lines that were read like that.

Comment: No problem. `readlines()` return a `list`. `len()` is simply reading the number of items in the `list`. If this is the answer that helped you, please mark as answer, thanks.